# Express relation between enum and its member in Python typing

Tags: python, enums, mypy, python-typing

How to type (in Python, e.g. for MyPy) a function that expects two parameters - an enum and one of its values/members?

```
from enum import Enum
from typing import TypeVar, Type

class MyEnumA(Enum):
   A = 1
   B = 2

class MyEnumB(Enum):
   A = 1
   B = 2

TE = TypeVar('TE', bound=Enum)
def myfunction(member: TE, e: Type[TE]) -> None:
    pass

myfunction(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumA) # all right
myfunction(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumB) # I expect mypy-error here but it passed

print(type(MyEnumA.A)) # says: <enum 'MyEnumA'>
print(type(MyEnumB.A)) # says: <enum 'MyEnumB'>

print(f'{isinstance(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumA)=}') # says: isinstance(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumA)=True
print(f'{isinstance(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumB)=}') # says: isinstance(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumB)=False

reveal_type(MyEnumA) # mypy: Revealed type is "def (value: builtins.object) -> e.MyEnumA"
reveal_type(MyEnumA.A) # mypy: Revealed type is "Literal[e.MyEnumA.A]?"
```

I would like to understand

- Why MyPy does not state an error for the second call; and
- How to type `myfunction` so that MyPy detects an error there.

More examples:

```
myfunction(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumA) # should pass - member of enum
myfunction(MyEnumB.A, MyEnumB) # should pass - member of enum
myfunction(MyEnumA.A, MyEnumB) # should fail - member of other enum
myfunction(MyEnumB.A, MyEnumA) # should fail - member of other enum
```

Comment: Mypy accepts this because you passed an enum instance and an enum class, so it's all fine. The main question for you is actually what you would like to do inside `myfunction`. Since it is annotated as accepting any enum, doing anything specific to a certain enum ( e.g. `e.A`) would be deemed invalid by mypy (because not all enums have `A`), and if you do only things which work on any enum, then it won't matter which enum you pass in.

Comment: @zvone myfunction is minimal type signature to formulate the question. You may thing of a function with one more parameter ```k: str``` that is a supposed to be a key in a dictionary ```d``` with a string that is supposed to be an enum member. The function shall check ```k in d``` and may return default ```member``` if  ```k not in d```. Then if ```k in d``` if should lookup ```k in e.__members__``` and return the value or raise more descriptive exception.

Comment: This kind of function is badly designed IMO. An enum should not be used like a dict. Looking up an enum member by a name is just as bad as looking up a method by its name. I'm not saying it should never be done, but it is out of mypy's score of interest, just as e.g. `getattr` would be.

Comment: @zvone How would you find enum's value from an input string e.g. in a configuration file else than looking it up in __members__? I do not expect MyPy to act on __members__. I expect it to check the function call against its type signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key observation is what MyPy actually considers a class MyEnumA to be:

```
reveal_type(MyEnumA) # mypy: Revealed type is "def (value: builtins.object) -> e.MyEnumA"
```

It gives a clue to annotate `myfunction` in the following way, no matter how unobvious it is:

```
P = ParamSpec('P')
def myfunction(member: TE, e: Callable[P, TE]) -> None:
```

That makes MyPy to find typing error in the second call of `myfunction`:

```
error: Argument 2 to "myfunction" has incompatible type "Type[MyEnumA]"; expected "Callable[[object], MyEnumB]"  [arg-type]
```

Comment: Wow. Now I'm 100% concerned that this is a bug. Please consider reporting at https://github.com/python/mypy/issues - despite the fact that `type[...]` is often reinterpreted as its `__init__` callable, it should not prevent proper inference with other `type` usage places. This is probably a complex case due to `Literal` + `Type` combination with `TypeVar` inference, but it certainly fits the issue tracker.

Comment: @SUTerliakov Reported as https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/15134